# Ionic 3 cordova native google maps

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic3

I am using the native Google Maps plugin in ionic and I am encountering a strange situation. Basically, I followed the example from the Ionic site. So when I start the app on androidn using `ionic cordova run android` this work fine. However, if I add `--livereload`, the map refuses the load. Actually, `GoogleMaps.create()` method returns an empty object `{}`. Anyone encountered this?

I am assuming that `--livereload` has a backend web server running that reloads the app which might cause the native plugin to fail?

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

For the livereload, insert `setTimeout()` before `GoogleMaps.create()`.
Because when the app executed `GoogleMaps.create()`, `platform.ready()` is not ready.

```
loadMap() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: This did not help. Tried increasing the timeout to as much as 3000, but nothing. The only way I can make it work is without --livereload

Comment: create is static in the new version of native Google maps.

Comment: Ok, please share your project files on github. I will check it. I have no problem with the above my answer.

Comment: Sorry can't share my project. Are you able to make it work with --livereload ? My current work around is not to use --livereload which works for now.

Comment: No sharing your code, I can't help you further more. As I said, I have no problem with the above my answer using `--livereload`